# Data from other controller to home controller MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So, I have the Home view and the Homecontroller. Now I want to populate data from a other view called Calendar (which also has a controller: CalendarController) in the Homecontroller view.

I've tried this already:

```
@model IEnumerable<GJL.Models.Calendar>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <div id="container" class="card shadow-2">

                        <div id="left">
                            <img id="image-calendar" src="~/TestImages/snapchat.png" />
                        </div>

                        <div id="middle">
                            <span style="font-family: 'Aldrich';">
                                <em class="date">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dag)</em>
                                <em class="month">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Maand)</em><br>
                                <em class="time">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tijd)</em>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <div id="right">
                            <h3 id="title-agenda" style="margin-top:0!important;margin-bottom:0!important;font-size: 2.8vw;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titel)</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 }
```

But it gives me a NullReferenceException. System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model.get returned null.

Why is this? I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you actually passing the expected Model (of type `IEnumerable<GJL.Models.Calendar>`) to this View? E.g. in the HomeController: `var vm = new List<GJL.Models.Calendar>(); return View("Home", vm);` If not, this explains the NullReference. Note that this is not the way to go, [use a partial view](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-partial-actions-and-partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc/) instead.

Comment: No, I didn't. Will try your solution. Am i supposed to use that piece of code in the Actionresult Index method?

Comment: Yes, put it into the action that renders the CSHTML you have shown. As I said, the clean way is to split the calendar view into a main view and a reusable partial view (which will also be used by home view) and split the Index (Calendar) action into a main action and partial action, and call this partial action from the home view. See the link I provided in my edit to the first comment.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Tried the first solution but the data wouldn't show up. Will use the partial view method.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider I'm stuck. I use a IEnumerable and it won't pass it. "InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'GJL.Models.Agenda', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[GJL.Models.Agenda]'.                               How to properly pass it? In controller already?

Comment: @RoyKooiman You're actually passing `GJL.Models.Agenda` in controller action but your `@model` directive has `@model IEnumerable<GJL.Models.Agenda>`. You need to return `List<GJL.Models.Agenda>` in controller to pass into view.

Comment: Yeah I saw that. That was wat I needed. Thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need exactly.But I think this info will help you. As I understood you need to pass data one controller to another controller and there's various way to do so...

You can use session like this way

```
Session["your_variable_name"] = your_value;
```

Or you can redirect controller with the value

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Nome", new{ your_variable_name: your_value})
```

or you can use tempdata also

```
TempData["your_variable_name"] = "your_value";
```